# Difference between embedding and containing

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I just saw the term embedding few times and was wondering its difference to containing.

Embedding says U is embedded in V if the identical map is bounded from U to V, i.e. $\|x\|_{V} \leq C\|x\|_{U}$ .

Containing says that $U \subset V $ if $x\in V, \forall x \in U$.

Seems to me embedding is the containing between normed spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Embedding and containing are very similar. However, embedding is a bit more "general" in that containing is embedding with the identity map. An embedding of $A$ into $B$ is using an injective homomorphism $\phi:A\to B$. In this sense, $A$ is almost like a subset of $B$, but it lives in a different world.

For example, $\mathbb Z$ is contained in $\mathbb R$, since the map $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(n)=n$ is the identity.

On the other hand, $\mathbb R$ can be embedded into $\mathbb R^2$ by the natural map $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $g(x)=(x,0)$. The big difference here is that $\mathbb R$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, since they do not have the same kinds of elements. However, the image of $g$ (which is $\mathbb R\times 0$) *is* contained in $\mathbb R^2$.

---

Said another way, if $A$ is contained in $B$, we can map all of the elements of $A$ to themselves in $B$, which is clearly an injective mapping. If $A$ can be embedded into $B$, then there exists an injective homomorphism $\phi:A\to B$. We can call the image of this map $\phi[A]$, and all of the elements of $\phi[A]$ could be directly mapped to themselves in $B$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's clear to me now. Just a tiny typo, I think you mean embedding is containing with the identity map in the second line?

Comment: No, to show containment, you can show it can be embedded with the identity map, just like the example with $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$. So, containment is embedding with the identity map.

Comment: Oh I get it. So embedding can deal with general injective homomorphism other than identity. I've only seen embedding with identity till now.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Showing something can be embedded means you can basically treat is like a subset.

Comment: Great, thank you for explaining in detail!